# Global Minimum solution for the Generator step in the original GAN formulation

Tags: optimization, gan

I am going through the proof in [Goodfellow's original GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf). Specifically, I'm at the stage where he did the discriminator step (solve a maximization problem) and now he is doing the generator step, that is $\min_{G} C(G)$ which is $\min_GV(G,D^{*})$.

He nicely shows that $p_g=p_{data}$ achieves the minimal value, $-\log(4)$. I get the proof. But then for fun I try to evaluate $C(G)$ with choosing $p_g := 0.5 \cdot p_{data} $.

So, plugging that into $$ \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{p_{data}}{p_{data}+p_g}}\rbrack +
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{g}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{p_{g}}{p_{data}+p_g}}\rbrack
$$

we get

$$ \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{p_{data}}{p_{data}+0.5\cdot p_{data}}}\rbrack +
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{g}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{0.5\cdot p_{data}}{p_{data}+0.5\cdot p_{data}}}\rbrack =
$$

$$ \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{1}{1.5}}\rbrack +
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{g}} \lbrack \log{
\frac{0.5}{1.5}}\rbrack = \log{\frac{2}{3}}+\log{\frac{1}{3}} =
$$
$$= -1.5041 (< -\log4= -1.3863)
$$

So it seems to me that if the generator optimizes for $p_g =0.5 \cdot p_{data} $ it actually achieves a better minimum for the target of the minimization problem.

To add further to my confusion, I ran the numbers in MATLAB (ignoring the expectation since I assume I'm taking it in a way such that $p_{data}$ cancels out, like before) and got the $-\log4$ is actually the maximum and not the minimum.

> [x,y] = meshgrid(0.01:0.001:1);
>
> f = log(x./(x+y))+log(y./(x+y));
>
> max(max(f))
>
> > ans =   -1.3863
>
> min(min(f))
>
> > ans =   -4.6251

I'll add that in my numerical experiment, the minimum was indeed achieved along the axis $x=y$. The minimum there collapses to the boundaries.

Why is this problem somehow minus-flipped in my head? I mean, we are trying to minimize it and not maximize it. I follow the proof that it is a global minima, so I don't see why am I getting lower values. is my choice somehow not permitted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, $p_g(x)=0.5p_{data}(x)$ is not a probability distribution, because $\sum_{x}p_g(x)=1$ must hold when summing over the latent space, whereas you will get $0.5$. So while $p_g(x)=0.5p_{data}(x)$ might hold for some set of $x\in X$, there must also be a set $Y$ such that $p_g(y)>0.5p_{data}(y)$ for all $y\in Y$.

For your second question, you're looking for the minimum of the expectations, which is not-at-all equivalent to minimizing the fixed function $\log(xy/(x+y)^2)$. Hence you need to consider the KL divergence between your generator and data distributions.